# Guide for custom UI controls

Tags: android

I want to develop an android application, but i dont want to use the default controls(buttons, checkboxes, radio buttons, etc.,). Is there any way to customize those controls to make it appear nicer. If so some tutorial or guide will help me a lot. Thanks....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to create completely new UI elements, you should read the [developer guide topic on creating custom components/views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).

If, on the other hand, you simply want to change the appearance of existing UI elements, below is a non-exhaustive list of things you'll need to do. This assumes you're familiar with the [Android resources framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html) and layout system.

- First, see how these are implemented in the Android source code ([AOSP](http://source.android.com), [GitHub's mirror](http://github.com/android/)). All of the code you're interested in is in the `frameworks/base.git` project (quick links: [resources](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/), [Java sources](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/java/android/widget/))
- For each type of UI element, create [Nine Patch PNG drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch) for each of the UI states (default, disabled, pressed, focused, etc.) and for each relevant density (e.g. medium, high , and extra-high densities). These PNGs should be in your `res/drawable-mdpi/`, `res/drawable-hdpi/`, and `res/drawable-xhdpi/` directories.
- For each type of UI element, create a [state list XML drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) (`<selector>`), which will be in your `res/drawable/` directory. The state list drawable for the default Android push button can be found [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/btn_default.xml).
- Set your button/textbox/etc.'s `android:background` attribute to the state list drawable name. For example, the attribute value should be `@drawable/mybutton` if your state list drawable is `res/drawable/mybutton.xml`. 
  *Note: You can use [themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) to reduce redundancy (i.e. keep them [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) in your XML files.*

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what im looking for.