# How can i create custom controls?

Tags: android, controls

I want to create a simple game.I need this information how to create custom controls

doubts:

1. Custom controls and OnScreen controls are same or different.
2. Next how to create custom controls
3. How to create onscreen controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly read the following official source:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Then you can check StackOverflow links for code samples:

[Where to find free open sourced android custom controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542678/where-to-find-free-open-sourced-android-custom-controls)

[Creating customs controls in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545906/creating-customs-controls-in-android)

[Guide for custom UI controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067792/guide-for-custom-ui-controls)

Comment: ok but tell me custom controls and Onscreen controls same or different pls if i ask any stupid question dont mine.....i am new for android application pls....

Comment: What do you mean by OnScreen controls? I guess you mean that are all controls displayed on the screen. Then it is not the same, you get the set of standard Android controls like Button, ImageView, ImageButton, Slider ... You can use them immediatelly. But, if you need controls that have somewhat different behaviour or look (which cannot be achieved through simple adjusting of the standard control parameters), then you need to customize them.

Comment: ok OnScreen controls means Like keys present in the game To turn left / right...Since it is touchscreen, some on screen contol to play the game....this type of controls how to create this is my doubts...

Comment: You can use ImageButton and set some nice icon as background (e.g. arrow for movement control) and that is all. No need for customization for now.