# Define and Populate a Layout for multiple activities

Tags: android

I have an app where I have to add an informative box in many acivities.
This box is basically a `LayoutView` with various `TextView` and an `ImageView`.

Is there a way to define he whole box in a single class and add this everytime that I need?

I could copy-paste both Layout xml code and methods tha populae the Layou for each Activity, but I want to avoid this (I really hate the redundant code).

Comment: Do you have any common struture for the layout ?

Comment: yes exacly....the layout have a common structure and he box will be placed at the bottom in each activity

Comment: Use tag include or write a custom component. Please post the image of the control you want to create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `Fragments`? They are meant to be reusable.

Comment: see the update on the question. could you give me more deails?

Answer (score 0):

yoh have tow option 
 the one is to make your box as different layout then you can include it on other layout
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html
the seacond is to create custom component
the link below will help you toward this
[How can i create custom controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966448/how-can-i-create-custom-controls)